# Is there any way to enable deliberate keyboard ghosting?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I want to deliberately turn on some form of keyboard ghosting on my keyboard. By [ghosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Ghosting) I mean the effect keyboards have when pressing multiple buttons at the same time, dropping the extra keyboard inputs when they exceed a certain number.

Specifically, I have a set of four keys (letters) and when I press two, I don't want it to register any third or fourth presses.

Are there any solutions such as software or configuring Windows 7 that might help me achieve this?

Comment: to be able to suggest alternative solutions, can you explain a bit about what you are trying to achive and what you are using it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unusual request... The only way I can think to do this is write your own script using autoHotKey. You can [block input](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/BlockInput.htm).